# Не работает функция в reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './navbar.module.css';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = (props) => {
    let friendElem = props.state.friends;
    let i = 0;
    console.log(friendElem[i].name);
    let friendList = friendElem.map((friendElem,i) => {<li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>});

    return (
    <nav className={classes.nav}>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div className={classes.home}></div>
                <NavLink to="/profile" className={classes.item} activeClassName={classes.activeLink} >Profile</NavLink>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div className={classes.dialogs}></div>
                <NavLink to="/dialogs" className={classes.item} activeClassName={classes.activeLink} >Dialogs</NavLink>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div className={classes.news}></div>
                <NavLink to="/news" className={classes.item} activeClassName={classes.activeLink} >News</NavLink>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div className={classes.music}></div>
                <NavLink to="/music" className={classes.item} activeClassName={classes.activeLink} >Music</NavLink>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div className={classes.settings}></div>
                <NavLink to="/settings" className={classes.item} activeClassName={classes.activeLink} >Settings</NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div className={classes.friends}>
            <h1>Friends</h1>
            <ul className={classes.friendList}>
                {friendList}
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>);
};
    export default Navbar;
```

Выводит это:

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/components/navbar/navbar.js   Line 9:  Expected an assignment or
>   function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error. This error
>   occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Убрать фигурные скобки. Ещё раз изучить синтаксис стрелочных функций

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ уже имеется, но можно предложить еще один вариант с небольшим пояснением. Как уже сказали, ошибка в следующем коде:

```
let friendList = friendElem.map(
  (friendElem, i) => {<li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>}
);
```

Дабы внести небольшую ясность, решил пролить свет на выражение стрелочной функции. А именно, когда вы пишете фигурные скобки `{}` после стрелки `=>` то Вы говорите JS коду, что внутри фигурных скобок будет находиться тело функции, из которого вы должны вернуть значение в случае необходимости.

> Тело стрелочной функции может иметь краткую (*concise body*) или
>   блочную (*block body*) форму. Блочная форма не возвращает значение,
>   необходимо явно вернуть значение.

То есть, можно просто дописать `return`:

```
let friendList = friendElem.map(
  (friendElem, i) => { return <li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>}
);
```

Либо заменить фигурные скобки `{}` на круглые скобки `()` и получится более короткая форма записи.

```
let friendList = friendElem.map(
  (friendElem, i) => (<li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>)
);
```

---

### Дополнительная полезная информация по стрелочным функциям

> Если единственным оператором в выражении стрелочной функции является
>   `return`, можно удалить `return` и окружающие фигурные скобки:

```
elements.map(element => element.example);
```

---

> Круглые скобки не обязательны для единственного параметра:

```
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

---

> Функция без параметров нуждается в круглых скобках:

```
() => { return expression; } // () => expression
```

---

> Заключите тело объекта в круглые скобки, чтобы вернуть литеральное выражение объекта:

```
params => ({ foo: bar })
```

Не забывайте о том, что возвращаемые объектные строки используют сокращённый синтаксис `{}` -  будут работать не так, как ожидается. Потому что код в скобках `{}` распознаётся как цепочка выражений, для примера:

```
() => { foo: 1 };
```

Здесь `foo` трактуется как наименование, а не как ключ в объектной строке. Не забывайте оборачивать круглыми скобками объектные строки. В противном случае могут возникать ошибки и сайд эффекты.

---

Полезная ссылка для изучения: [**Стрелочные функции**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте заменить

```
let friendList = friendElem.map((friendElem,i) => {<li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>});
```

на

```
let friendList = friendElem.map((friendElem,i) => (<li><div></div><span>{friendElem[i].name}</span></li>));
```

Т.е. заменить фигурные скобки на круглые. Или вообще убрать фигурные скобки. Как больше нравится.

В таком случае колбэк из map начнёт возвращать значение и это исправит ошибку.